# Why can't I RUN npm install on my Node Lambda Dockerfile?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, dockerfile

Trying to convert my Python dockerfile to Node dockerfile
Screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/QPFD3WY

Working Python Dockerfile

```
> Add New Relic Extension & AWS Python Base Image
> FROM public.ecr.aws/x6n7b2o2/newrelic-lambda-layers-python:311-arm64 AS Extension
> FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11
> Extension code
> WORKDIR /opt
> COPY --from=Extension /opt/ .
> Copy requirements.txt
> COPY requirements.txt ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
> Copy all files in ./src
> COPY src/* ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
> Install the specified packages
> RUN pip freeze > requirements.txt
> RUN pip install -r /var/task/requirements.txt
> Set the CMD to your handler.
> CMD [ "main.handler" ]
```

Node Dockerfile

```
# Add New Relic Extension & AWS Python Base Image
FROM public.ecr.aws/x6n7b2o2/newrelic-lambda-layers-nodejs:18-arm64 AS Extension
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:18 AS base
# Extension code
WORKDIR /opt
COPY --from=Extension /opt/ .
COPY src/* ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY package*.json /usr/app/
RUN npm install
# Set the CMD to your handler.
CMD [ "index.handler" ]
```

Error Message

```
> [base 7/7] RUN npm install:
0.578 npm ERR! code ENOENT
0.578 npm ERR! syscall open
0.578 npm ERR! path /usr/app/package.json
0.578 npm ERR! errno -2
0.579 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/app/package.json'
```

I changed the path, but it's still throwing the same error. Moving package.json file to image folder is giving the same error as well

```
COPY ../../package*.json ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
```

Comment: since you changed your work directory to `/usr/app` the copy command is putting the `package.json` file into `/usr/app/usr/app`. change the copy command to be `COPY package*.json .` so it uses the relative path of the work directory. [More information here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)